# Lie-Derivative, Inner Product and Outer Derivative - Two Identities

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to proof the following two identities:
$$\mathcal{L}_Xi_Y\omega = i_{\mathcal{L}_X Y}\omega + i_Z\mathcal{L}_X \omega$$
where $i_X \omega$ is the inner product of the vector field $X \in \mathcal{V}^k(M)$ with the $n$-form $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$.
The second identity is then:
$$
\mathcal{L}_X d\omega = d\mathcal{L}_X \omega$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lie-derivative with respect to some vector field and $d$ denotes the outer derivative.

For the first theorem I've no idea how to show that. I calculated down to local coordinates but then got stuck with the notation.
For the second identity I've accomplished the following
$$
d\mathcal{L}_X\omega = d(\frac{d}{dt} (\phi^X_t)^*(df\wedge dx_{i1} \wedge \ldots dx_{1n}))\\
=d(\frac{d}{dt}d(f\circ\phi^X_t)\wedge d(x_{i1}\circ\phi^X_t) \wedge \ldots d(x_{in}\circ \phi^X_t))$$

I tried to compute the identities in local coordinates … where I failed with the notation and then I tried to use the identity $\mathcal{L}_X = i_X \circ d + d \circ i_x$.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished to proof the second identity:
$$(i_X \circ d + d \circ i_X) = i_X \circ d \circ d + d \circ i_X \circ d = d \circ i_X \circ d$$
and
$$d\circ(i_X \circ d + d \circ i_X) = d \circ i_X \circ d + d \circ d \circ i_X = d \circ i_X \circ d$$
Hence the identity holds.